# How to change height of DropdownButton in flutter

Tags: flutter, dropdownbutton

How can I change the height of a DropdownButton in flutter.
I have tried to use Padding and SizedBox but none is realy working.

SizedBox just increases the container size while the DropdownButton is clamped to top left and therefore is not centered anymore.
Padding is ignored or moves the content outside of the button.

I do not want to change the size of the dropdown overlay but the button itself.

```
build(BuildContext context) {
  return ThemeData(
    data: ThemeData(canvasColor: Colors.white),
    child: DropdownButton(
      items: _items.map((item) => DropdownMenuItem(child: Text(item), value: item)).toList(),
      isExpanded: true,
      selectedItemBuilder: (_) {
        return _items.map<Widget>((String lang) {
          return Center(
            widthFactor: 1,
            child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12),
              child: Text(lang, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black))
            ),
          );
        }).toList();
      }
    )
  )
}
```

Comment: menuMaxHeight: 300 this solves it

Answer (score 15):

Wrap it in a `Container`, give a height, width as per your need and set `isExpanded` true in `DropDownButton`. Also change dropdownbutton text font size as per your need.

```dart
Container(
  height: 50.0,
  width: 200.0,
  child: DropdownButton(
           value: dropdownValue,
           icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward),
           iconSize: 24,
           elevation: 16,
           isExpanded: true,
           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple, fontSize: 20.0),
           underline: Container(
             height: 2,
             color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
           ),
           onChanged: (String newValue) {
             setState(() {
               dropdownValue = newValue;
             });
           },
           items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
               .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
             return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
               value: value,
               child: Text(value),
             );
           }).toList(),
         )
)
```

End product should look something like this,

[image]

Answer (score 10):

Looks like the 'itemHeight' property for the DropdownButton class should do the trick. I tried it and it increased the height of my DropdownButton.

Here is some sample code I have from a previous project using the itemHeight:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
      itemHeight: 100.0,
      value: selectedCurrency,
      items: dropdownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() {
          selectedCurrency = value;
          getData();
        });
      },
    );
```

Note: Just make sure the value you provide isn't less than 48.0, since it will give an error.

Docs:
itemHeight property: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/itemHeight.html

Minimum itemHeight defined by 'kMinInteractiveDimension':
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/kMinInteractiveDimension-constant.html

Answer (score 7):

```
itemHeight: null,
```

You just need to leave the itemHeight with the *null* value.

It will make the height of the DropdownButton with the menu item's intrinsic height.

Answer (score 6):

**Use SizedBox Widget**

```
SizedBox(
      height: 30,
      child:DropdownButton<String>(
      value: selectedCurrency,
      items: dropdownItems,
      onChanged: (value) {},
    ))
```

Answer (score 5):

You need to use [menuMaxHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/menuMaxHeight.html) property of DropdownButton Widget.

```
child: DropdownButton(
 menuMaxHeight: 500.0,
 value: '1',
 items: setTotalPages(),
 onChanged: (String? newValue) {
 setState(() {
 dropdownvalue = newValue!;
 });
},
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I used InputDecorationTheme to meet the need.

```
  List<int> weekList = List.generate(52, (index) => index + 1);
  int? selectedWeek;

DropdownMenu<int>(
                      inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(height: 40),
                        enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
                            Radius.circular(10),
                          ),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            width: 1.2,
                            color: Colors.blue,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      initialSelection: weekList.first,
                      controller: colorController,
                      menuHeight: 200,
                      label: const Text('Select week'),
                      dropdownMenuEntries: weekList
                          .map(
                            (int item) => DropdownMenuEntry<int>(
                              value: item,
                              label: item.toString(),
                              style: const ButtonStyle(
                                backgroundColor:
                                    MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.red),
                              ),
                            ),
                          )
                          .toList(),
                      onSelected: (int? color) {
                        setState(
                          () {
                            selectedWeek = color;
                          },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest of all methods is using `DropDownButton2` which is built over DropDownButton

And just change the `buttonHeight` attribute

Not just `buttonHeight` , you can even change `itemHeight` , `buttonwidth` and many more customize

```
String? selectedValue;
List<String> items = [
  'Item1',
  'Item2',
  'Item3',
  'Item4',
];

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
        child: DropdownButton2(,
          items: items
                  .map((item) =>
                  DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: item,
                    child: Text(
                      item,
                     ),
                  ))
                  .toList(),
          value: selectedValue,
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
            });
          },
          buttonHeight: 40,
          buttonWidth: 140,
          itemHeight: 40,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

checkout : [DropDownButton2](https://pub.dev/packages/dropdown_button2) for more examples.

Hope it helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Add this property menuMaxHeight: 200,  to DropdownButton